# Automating UI Testing in Flutter and Detecting Overflow Errors

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

I'm relatively new to Flutter testing, and I'm seeking some advice on how to automate UI testing for my Flutter app. My main goal is to ensure that my app's user interface works seamlessly on different mobile devices and screen sizes while also being able to identify any overflow errors that might occur.

Is there a way to automatically verify that the UI functions correctly across a variety of devices and screen sizes? Are there any scripts or tools available that can assist with this? Thanks

Comment: Cool question. Hope some-guru give us solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use golden test with alchemist package.
By this way, you could setup scenarios.
Also, you can run golden test in cicd.
This is one of tutorial I found it.
https://verygood.ventures/blog/alchemist-golden-tests-tutorial